# React Native Navigator Wix - BorderTop don't appears on the Bottom Tabs

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm having an issue when using the bottom tabs, on the iOS emulator I see `BorderTop` but When I open the application on iOS Device It not appears. Did anyone had similar issues?

Set root and Default settings:

```
 Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
        bottomTabs: {
          backgroundColor: '#FFF',
          titleDisplayMode: 'alwaysShow',
        },


const setRoot = () => ({
  root: {
    bottomTabs: {
      children: [
        {
          stack: {
            children: [
              {
                component: {
                  name: screen.FEED_SCREEN,
                },
              },
            ],
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                icon: Icons.myProfile,
                text: 'Screen 1',
                badge: '1',
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          stack: {
            children: [
              {
                component: {
                  name: 'UIPlayground',
                },
              },
            ],
            options: {
              bottomTab: {
                icon: Icons.myProfile,
                text: 'Screen 2',
                badge: '2',
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

I'm using versions:

```
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-navigation": "^7.4.0"
```

Simulator:

[image]

Device:

[image]